# namespace based folding unsorted menu in dokuwiki

Tags: menu, indexing, folding, dokuwiki

I want to create  a folding sidebar menu for my dokuwiki. I am using indexmenu plugin for this purpose.
This is how the menu is displayed currently
SoftwareUserManual is my namespace and the menu items are pages in the namespace. I need to display the folding menu in my dokuwiki sidebar

```
SoftwareUserManual
 .Configuration 
 .ExportingImportingConfigurations
 .GlobalConfiguration
 .Installation
 .UserConfiguration

 .Uninstalling
```

I want to display the menu in the following way. No alphabetical sorting and space between the words.

```
Software User Manual
 .Installation
 .Configuration 
 .Global Configuration
 .User Configuration
 .Exporting/Importing Configurations
 .Uninstalling
```

Any idea how can I do that or is there any alternate to indexmenu that can help me

Answer (score 1):

https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:indexmenu#metadata_tag_syntax

> By default nodes on the same tree level are sorted by name (or by title/date if you use the tsort/dsort syntax), but you can also specify a custom sort number for every page inserting a metadata tag in the pages with this syntax:

```
 {{indexmenu_n>N}}
```

> Where N is a number. Then you need to use the “msort” option in your indexmenu tree syntax. If you have the show_sort option enabled in the Configuration Manager, a notice is displayed to admins (only) on every page with this metadata tag (the text defaults to “Indexmenu sort number: N”).

https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:indexmenu#namespaces_title_and_link_headpages

> Titles for page headings
>
> First of all, if you want that the whole tree displays the heading title of pages instead of their name, you need to set the config setting useheading on in the general configuration of the wiki. Indexmenu will show page titles when useheading is 'always' or 'navigation'